# How to use bower package manager with access restricted dependencies

Tags: bower

How do you add an access restricted repo as dependency to your bower.json without providing the user credentials in the bower.json?

i.e. I want to avoid specifying it like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.0.6",
    "restricted": "https://<username>:<password>@gitserver.tld/restricted"
  }
}
```

I'd rather like bower / git ask me for credentials during install.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using ssh-copy-id that way you could atleast not have to give away your password.

it can be installed through homebrew.

```
brew install ssh-copy-id
```

and to use it

```
ssh-copy-id myuser@gitserver.tld
```